# When was brain cancer first discovered?

Tags: cancer, brain, history

Does anyone know:
In which year was the first brain tumor discovered?

Comment: Cancer itself was well known in prehistoric times, but I can't tell you anything about brain tumors specifically. Anyway, if the topic interests you, I once saw an author's presentation of this book and it seemed like a very good read: http://www.amazon.de/The-Emperor-All-Maladies-Biography/dp/1439170916.

Comment: Hmm this meta seems to suggest we find this question relevant on health.SE. [Are questions about medical history on topic?](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/18/are-questions-about-medical-history-on-topic) I'll leave this here in case people have questions about historical relevance in health.SE like I did.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [source](http://web.archive.org/web/20150225220724/http://discovery.yukozimo.com/who-discovered-brain-cancer/) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_brain_cancer), brain cancer was first discovered in 1873 and brain tumor before that. We can't say for sure when the first case of brain tumor occurred because it may have been originated in the prehistoric times. Since no data was recorded in those times, it isn't certain to say when and where the first case of brain tumor occurred.

> It’s not that hard to answer the question of who discovered brain cancer – this breakthrough is credited to Gupta Longati, a Russian scientist, who discovered the disease in 1873.

Comment: Your link is now dead.

Comment: Please write those important lines from your source here as it is _gone_. That is the problem of linked answers:(

Comment: I don't think information about "Gupta Longati" is reliable. Only 200 Google results about him, wiki doesn't say anything about him nowhere. I'm sure at least some Encyclopedia should have such information.

Comment: @kenorb Maybe it didn't in 2015 when you commented, but Wikipedia does credit him now. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timeline_of_brain_cancer

Comment: The only source on Wikipedia is the link to another Q&A page with no author who wrote it and external page-not-found page with no cached page, so it's pretty bad source.

Comment: @kenorb Agreed, but a web search on his name or "who discovered brain cancer" turns up about 1500 hits, all agreeing on Gupta. Could just be an echo chamber of a bad original source, but it's all there seems to be.

Answer (score -3):

I have heard it was discovered in 1879. There were some cases before that of people with the same symptoms, but doctors didn't know what it was.

Comment: Please note that this site (unlike many on SE) requires [sources which support answers](http://meta.health.stackexchange.com/questions/283/) . Please see the [site tour](http://health.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help sections](http://health.stackexchange.com/help) for more information about Health.SE.

Comment: @JohnP: `(unlike many on SE)`: what do you want to mean by that? Every site does require source-authenticity & specifications that support answer or any query. Just write any answer on History SE; you would be immediately approached by a mod to cite any source for the claim; same is in the case of Skeptics SE. So, those words do not fit at all:/

Comment: @user36790 ELL and ELU are more flexible on using references, for example (it depends on the sort of question being asked), world building, puzzles and academia SE rarely have references at all... But it is discussed on meta why references are so important when answering questions about health.

Comment: Many SE sites don't require citations. In fact, stackoverflow, the original SE site, doesn't. Bicycles, cooking, superuser, home improvement, woodworking, aviation, pets, and a host of others also don't.